# Create object with code in VB6

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

i have a program in Visual Basic 6, and i need create a button in my program with code.

I write this code:

```
private sub Pulso_click()
    dim boton as CommandButton
    set boton = new CommandButton
    boton.width = 100
    boton.height = 30
    boton.caption = "MiBoton"

End Sub
```

but don't run. i have "El uso de la palabra clave New no es valido",
in english "keyword New use invalid".

This run in Visual Basic 6

Where is the problem??? Thanks

Comment: you need to now add the button control "boton" to your form (the UI application window)

Comment: rather than adding controls to forms programmatically at runtime, a better approach, in my opinion, would be to add the button during design time, and simply hide/show it when needed.

Comment: It helps to be specific too.  Creating a Control dynamically requires different steps than creating an instance of a simple Class.  Sure, they're both "objects," but the difference makes all of the difference in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not look like it stems from the VB6 IDE. I suppose you have an IDE, right? If so:

You can't create a CommandButton by code just so. If you want one at runtime, you need a control field. To make a control field, place a CommandButton control on your form. Give it the Index 0. Set its Visible property to False.

Your code seems to imply pixels. Set the form's ScaleMode property to 3 - Pixels.

Now you can create further instances from this template.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Load Command1(1)
    With Command1(1)
        .Top = 10
        .Left = 10
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 30
        .Caption = "MiBoton 1"
        .Visible = True
        .ZOrder
    End With

    Load Command1(2)
    With Command1(2)
        .Top = 10
        .Left = 120
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 30
        .Caption = "MiBoton 2"
        .Visible = True
        .ZOrder
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You can create a command button 'just by code' look at the first example I gave in my answer, that's a dynamic control.

Comment: Thanks Herb, a pretty solution.

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me

```
 Option Explicit
'
Dim WithEvents Cmd1 As CommandButton
'
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Set Cmd1 = Controls.Add("vb.commandbutton", "Cmd1")
  Cmd1.Width = 2000
  Cmd1.Top = Me.Height / 2 - Cmd1.Height / 2 - 100
  Cmd1.Left = Me.Width / 2 - Cmd1.Width / 2 - 100
  Cmd1.Caption = "Dynamic Button"
  Cmd1.Visible = True
End Sub
'
Private Sub Cmd1_click()
  MsgBox "I have been Created Dynamically at Run-time", _
    , "Dynamic Controls"
End Sub
'
```

[image]

Works with no problems for me, I hope this code works for you, You can also use indexes create one command button and set the index to zero then on form load or whenever you want it to show

```
Load Command1(1)
Command1(1).Caption = "command2"
Command1(1).Left = Command1(0).Left + Command1(0).Width
Command1(1).Top = Command1(0).Top
Command1(1).Visible = True
```

You get the point, good luck, I use indexes myself lots of times when I have a bunch of controls it loads faster this way, enjoy.